# Barra de scroll vertical a la izquierda de un ScrollPane en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

¿Usando `Java FX` Es posible colocar la barra de scroll vertical de un `scrollPane` a la izquierda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es:

1. Crear un `ScrollBar`
2. Asociar mediante `bind` el `ScrollBar` con el `ScrollPane`
3. Esconder la barra de scroll vertical del `ScrollPane`

Aquí hay un pequeño ejemplo funcional:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class ScrollbarIzquierda extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            Line line = new Line(100, 100, 1000, 1000);
            pane.getChildren().add(line);

            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setContent(pane);

            ScrollBar vScrollBar = new ScrollBar();
            vScrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
            vScrollBar.minProperty().bind(scrollPane.vminProperty());
            vScrollBar.maxProperty().bind(scrollPane.vmaxProperty());
            vScrollBar.visibleAmountProperty().bind(scrollPane.heightProperty().divide(pane.heightProperty()));
                scrollPane.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(vScrollBar.valueProperty());

            ScrollBar hScrollBar = new ScrollBar();
            hScrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
            hScrollBar.minProperty().bind(scrollPane.hminProperty());
            hScrollBar.maxProperty().bind(scrollPane.hmaxProperty());
            hScrollBar.visibleAmountProperty().bind(scrollPane.widthProperty().divide(pane.heightProperty()));
            scrollPane.hvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(hScrollBar.valueProperty());

scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            HBox.setHgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
            hBox.getChildren().addAll(vScrollBar, scrollPane);

            VBox vBox = new VBox();
            VBox.setVgrow(hBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
            vBox.getChildren().addAll(hScrollBar, hBox);

            Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 500, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            vScrollBar.requestLayout();
            hScrollBar.requestLayout();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Y el CSS:

```
.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.scroll-pane:focused {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.scroll-pane .corner {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Desgraciadamente no, en un **[`Scroll Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/scrollpane.htm)**, únicamente puedes manipular propiedades de las barras Horizontal cuya posición es abajo y Vertical posición derecha, que son las únicas implementadas para este control.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]